# div width and height proportional to screen width

Tags: html, css

I have four divs which I want to enlarge and collapse based on the screen width. The min-width should be 320px because I am using CSS grid and want to render one div at a time on mobile screen. However as the screen size increases I want the divs to enlarge but keeping the same width and height ratio. I looked at few other similar question on Stackoverflow but those were not related to what I wanted to achieve. Any help would be really appreciated.

```css
.inner-tile {
  display: grid;
  max-width: calc(320px * 4 + 20px * 3);
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.event {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px #e3e3e3;
  /*border: 1px solid grey;*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.event-image {
  background: url('club.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="tile" id="events">
  <h2>header...</h2>
  <div class="inner-tile">
    <div class="event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">Event</a>
      <!-- <h6>learn more</h6> -->
    </div>
    <div class="event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">Event</a>
      <!-- <h6>learn more</h6> -->
    </div>
    <div class="event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">Event</a>
      <!-- <h6>learn more</h6> -->
    </div>
    <div class="event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">Event</a>
      <!-- <h6>learn more</h6> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Just a note: `max-width: calc(320px * 4 + 20px * 3);` will always be the same as `max-width: 1340px;` - no need for `calc` here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make any element relative to screen width, and not its container's width, use the `vw` unit, which stands for view width. This gets around `position: absolute`, too.

```css
.inner-tile {
    width: 25vw;
    //...
}
```

Comment: and `vh` for the height. this is what I was thinking.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this as a base for keeping the ratio of a div

```css
.ratio {
  position:relative;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.ratio::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* ratio 16/9 */
}

.ratio-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  <div class="ratio-content">
    content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: too vague. could you please explain which div's css should i edit